# Sending information from iOS to macOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, macos, macos-sierra

I'm working on an app for iOS and macOS and should be installed on both devices (iOS device and Mac computer) to work.

I want an option to send strings from the iOS device to the Mac (for example: if the user writes "Hello World!" and presses "transfer" button I want to get it instantly on the Mac app).

What is the best option to send strings from an iOS app to a macOS app (it should work even when the device isn't near the computer and even if it's not connected to the same WIFI network)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two Options:

1. Server on MacOS + Client on iOS + Port Forwarding (Router)
2. Client on MacOS + Client on iOS + Server in the Internet

You would usually go for the second option because the user doesn't need to configure Port Forwarding.

The connection would be a HTTP(S) connection. On MacOS and iOS there are APIs available which support HTTP(S).

(If you need a more specific answer you need to ask a more specific question)

Comment: And then to use silent push notification from the server (for example: Parse)?

Comment: For pushes you could go for a WebSocket connection which buildn on top of HTTP. Whith that you get bidirectional messaging.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know exactly what WebSocket connection is. Do you know where can I learn the basics that I need for my project?

Comment: I would start with the basics of networking. Then learn something about HTTP. Then send messages from a client to a server in practice. Then read about WebSocket and Sockets in general. It is a long way to master all these things but it is worth it. Just google for the topics :)